# "server could not find the requested resource (get pods)" error when deploying Helm chart using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my Kubernetes Helm chart for sample Kubernetes cluster deployment. I created a sample Helm chart and added Docker image reference and deployed the Helm chart using terminal command `helm install <my-chartname>`. And micro service is accessing successfully without any problem.

After that I created a Jenkins pipeline job and added only one stage that containing the step for deployment. I added like the following way,

```
pipeline 
{
    agent any
    stages 
        {
            stage ('helmchartinstall')
                {
                    steps
                    {
                        sh 'helm install spacestudychart'
                    }
                }
        }       
}
```

And I am getting the error like following ,

```
[Pipeline] { (helmchartinstall)
[Pipeline] sh
+ helm install spacestudychart
Error: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods)
```

The same command is working when I am running through terminal.

**Update**

To upgrade tiller to latest version, I run the `helm init --upgrade` command on terminal. But the error remains still.

**Output of "helm version" is like the following,**

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7fd0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.0", GitCommit:"05811b84a3f93603dd6c2fcfe57944dfa7ab7fd0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

**Output of "kubectl version --short" is like the following,**

```
Client Version: v1.14.1
Server Version: v1.13.5
```

When I run command "kubectl --v=5 get pods; helm install spacestudychart" , I am getting the console output like the following,

```
+ kubectl --v=5 get pods
I0604 07:44:46.035459    2620 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I0604 07:44:46.152770    2620 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I0604 07:44:46.152819    2620 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I0604 07:44:46.283598    2620 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I0604 07:44:46.374088    2620 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
I0604 07:44:46.467938    2620 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
F0604 07:44:46.468122    2620 helpers.go:114] error: yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE
```

Do I need to upgrade the kubectl version? What is the exact problem when running with Jenkins?

Comment: It's very likely because your credentials are incorrect, or in the unlikely case that the credentials do not have a `RoleBinding` (or `ClusterRoleBinding`) that grants them access to the Pods resource; running `kubectl get pods` right before that helm command may help distinguish the two, optionally with `--v 15` to surface the actual underlying error message

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - But the same command is successfully working when I am running through terminal. And I accessed the out put end point also. Error is getting only when I added the command into jenkins pipeline script. And Thank you for your response sir.

Comment: _"running through terminal"_ as jenkins, or you mean that _your_ kubeconfig is correct? That's why I offered to put a `get pods` in the jenkins script, so it would run under the same circumstances as does your helm command

Comment: Yes sir. From terminal it is running properly. And I am able to access my rest APIs also.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Error getting only when I am running through jenkins pipeline job. By using terminal  I am able to deploy and successfully getting the end point also.

Comment: I feel as though you are not hearing me; update your Jenkins pipeline to read `steps { sh 'kubectl --v=5 get pods; helm install spacestudychart'` and report the output here, because -- as I pointed out -- just because it works **for you** does not mean it works **for jenkins**; there are all kinds of things that can cause Jenkins to be misconfigured

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel - Yes , I run the command and updated the output in above question. Can u please look on that ?

Comment: Check your kubeconfig in ur jenkins run time.. those don't look right. Check for keys being in the wrong indentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is 100% working I have this problem before.

At first builts jenkins user next
copy `config` to `/home/jenkins/.kube/`

```
cp $HOME/.kube/config /home/jenkins/.kube/ 
or 
cp ~/.kube/config /home/jenkins/.kube/
```

And after that use

```
 chmod 777 /home/jenkins/.kube/config
```

your kubernetes command need your kubernetes config file . it is like key or password for your kubernetes cluster so you should give the kubernetes config to your jenkins and after that it can run kubernetes commands

This is very good tutorial that help me to solve it .

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=288rTpd1SDE)

**UPDATE1**
you should have jenkins user for adding jenkins user you should add jenkins user to your ubuntu or centos or ..

```
adduser jenkins
```

This is good link to adduser
[Adding user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-quickstart)

**UPDATE 2**
You should install kubectl in your server that you use it as `jenkins` so that kubectl command can work and after that please copy the config in `~/.kube/config` in your `kubernetes` cluster to your `jenkins` server that previously you installed `kubectl` on it.

Comment: I don't think giving everyone access to the `.kube/config` is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. But i don't have jenkins directory in my $HOME. I was installed jenkins through ansible playbook. So in this case what i can do here?

Comment: you should add jenkins user

Comment: adduser jenkins

Comment: If you do not have jenkins in your home so you do not have jenkins user. In home you can see users as directory.It is very important to have jenkins user because jenkins dashboard run your code as jenkins user

Comment: But my jenkins is working properly. And when I putted cat passwd , it listing the jenkins user group also. Jenkins I am running as root privillege.

Comment: yes this command work but your kubernetes command need your kubernetes config file . it is like key or password for yout kubernetes cluster so you should give the kubernetes config to your jenkins and after that it can run kubernetes commands

Comment: when I added jenkins , it giving the jenkins already exists.But not listing in $HIOME directory

Comment: If user by the name of jenkins is exist certainly you should see jenkins directory in your /home
delete the existing jenkins user and build an other one.
what is your OS?ubuntu?centos?

Comment: do you install kubectl in the server that you use as jenkins?

Comment: `jenkins` user by default does not have a default login shell. Jenkins $HOME is normally `/var/lib/jenkins`

Answer (score 2):

### kubectl version

As per [`kubectl` version skew policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl):

> **kubectl** is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of
>   **kube-apiserver**.

So there is no problem to use **v1.14** client with **v1.13** server version.

---

### helm issue

The error that you described usually happens when a previous release already exists with the same name. You can check this with `helm ls --all`. If it is the case, you should use [`helm upgrade`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_upgrade.md) instead.

There is a great chance that the existing release is in a `FAILED` state. If so, even `helm upgrade` may fail. You can delete the release with `helm delete spacestudychart --purge`, and try to install it again with `helm install`.

The helm tiller stores release info as ConfigMaps, so another cause of the problem may be invalid data for a "broken" release. If you have this problem your scenario should look like this:

```
$ helm ls --all

$ kubectl get cm --all-namespaces -l OWNER=TILLER
NAMESPACE     NAME               DATA   AGE
kube-system   spacestudychart.v1   1      22h
```

In that case, delete the ConfigMap and try to install the release again:

```
$ kubectl delete cm  spacestudychart.v1 -n kube-system
```

Comment: If it is helm problem it supposed to fail from terminal also. But when I am running through terminal , it is successfully working. And I am able to access my ReST APIs also. So do I need to follow your guided way ? I had confusion because of this. From terminal helm install command successfully working. Thank you for your response sir

Comment: Only issue getting when I am running through terminal.

Comment: I done the same what you given here. But still the same error getting.

Answer (score 1):

> F0604 07:44:46.468122    2620 helpers.go:114] error: yaml: line 10: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Indicates that `$HOME/.kube/config` (or whatever file is pointed to by the environment variable `$KUBECONFIG`) is invalid yaml; without seeing the contents of it one cannot say for sure what the fix is, other than "fix your kubeconfig" but that is for sure the correct answer, even if it isn't as actionable as we both might like

Answer (score 1):

> The same command is working when I am running through terminal.

I suspect that you might be running commands from the terminal as `root` user, which will have access to your `kubeconfig`.

The jenkins pipelines will run under `jenkins` user, which may or may not have read access to the `kubeconfig` file. Make sure that `jenkins` user has read access to this file.